# parsing a xml file which contains more than one keyvalues using c#

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I have file format

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<root>
  <file id="001">
    <filename>ABC.wav</filename>
    <value>0.18</value>
  </file>
  <file id="002">
    <filename>EFG.wav</filename>
    <value>0.05</value>
    <value>0.14</value>
  </file>
</root>
```

I want to parse that USING C#

```
doc.Load(confidencethresholdFilePath+"\\model.xml");
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/root/file");

List<Result> results = new List<Result>();

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Result result = new Result();
    result.ASfilename= node.SelectSingleNode("filename").InnerText;
    result.resultedSeconds = node.SelectSingleNode("value").InnerText;
    results.Add(result);
}
```

It gives result but misses the second record's second value.How do i get all results without fail.

Comment: You use `SelectSingleNode` which return a single node as the name says. Use `SelectNodes` for `value`

Answer (score 1):

How about using LINQ to XML?

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.xml");

var results =
    xDoc.Root
        .Elements("file")
        .Select(f => new
        {
            FileName = (string)f.Element("filename"),
            Values = f.Elements("value").Select(v => (string)v).ToList()
        })
        .ToList();
```

`results` will be a list of anonymous type instances with two properties: `FileName:string` and `Values:List<string>`. You can easily change it to return `List<Record>` instead, just change `f => new` to `f => new Record` and update properties info.

As you can see, it's much easier to get XML content using LINQ to XML than using old-style `XmlSomething` classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a separate Result for each value and using your non-Linq style, you could change the initial selection. The file name selection will then need to change appropriately.

```
doc.Load(confidencethresholdFilePath+"\\model.xml");
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/root/file/value");
List<Result> results = new List<Result>();
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Result result = new Result();
    result.ASfilename= node.SelectSingleNode("../filename").InnerText;
    result.resultedSeconds = node.SelectSingleNode("value").InnerText;
    results.Add(result);
}
```